# integers with octal and hexadecimal values and their operations

Tags: java

I am beginner in java, I came up with a doubt in java which I would like to clarify.

we can initialize a integer variable with a hexadecimal or octal values, but when we display the values (with hexa or octal) on the screen, it is displayed in decimal values. how can we make the output to be displayed in octal or hexadecimal?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        int a, b;
        a = 0xA1;
        b = 07;
        System.out.println("a = " + a);
        System.out.println("b = " + b);
        System.out.println("a + b = " + (a + b));
}
```

What I am expecting is when I display the value in variable a it should display its assigned octal value 0XA1
please help me out
Output :

```
a = 161
b = 7
a + b = 168
```

also please explain me how the addition between two integer numbers of different bases(between a octal and hexadecimal) would take place, would there be any conversion between bases, and what would the base of the number resulting from the addition of two integers of different bases?

Comment: here is the output displayed in decimal

Comment: a=161 b= 7 a+b=167

Comment: [Formatting Numeric Print Output - The Java Tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/numberformat.html)

Comment: As for your question about wether any "conversions" would take place: No, obviously inside your computer the numbers will allways be stored in binary format.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please don't post your code as a screenshot; it's much better to use the code tags, so that people can easily copy and paste your code to test it, and similar. Also, image services are often blocked by corporate firewalls, so you will be reducing the number of people who are able to help you. For other tips on how to help people give you good answers, please have a read of [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Java (as any other programming language) uses an *internal number representation* which is on base 2 (binary).

When you assing a number value to a variable the *compiler* converts the *human readable number representation* you typed in your source file into the *internal number representation*.

When you output the number stored in your variable the runtime converts this number back to *human readable number representation*.
Since there are a few it uses the most common one by default (decimal digits).

You as the developer decide if the program should output the number in some other representation like *hex*, *octal*, or *binary*.
So if you want you numbers to be outputted in the same representation as they have been entered then you have to provide some information at runtime.
The language itself does not support this requirement.

Comment: thank you for helping me, but can you please enlighten me about the additional information which i am suppose to provide in run time for getting the numbers outputted in the same representation as i have entered.

Comment: @USer you need an additional variable to store that information. But the more interesting quuestion is: do you really need this information? Do you really want to change the *runtime output* depending on the format you entered the value at *compile time*? Don't you rather want to make the output depending on the *semantic meaning* of the variable?

Comment: thanks for explanation. can you please me more specific on the additional information which should be given in another (additional) variable. if possible please explain with a code.

Answer (score 0):

Like in c you can do this in java

```
System.out.printf("%x", a)
```

This will output the hexadecimal format